# Is it possible to supply a custom objective function of categorical data to xgboost in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I have categorical data and an objective function that I'm trying to optimize. In xgboost docs, it's mentioned that you can supply your own objective function but it must return the gradient and hessian. I'm not sure what the hessian or gradient means when I have categorical data. The objective function looks somewhat like this

```
sum_{all classes i} ((number of correct predictions in class_i) / (number in class i))
```

Is it possible to create a custom objective function in this case?

Answer (score 0):

To analytically calculate the gradient and hessian(2nd derivative) of an objective function, you need to define it in terms of your model's predictions and given true labels. 
From your objective function it is clear that you are optimizing a weighted accuracy(without percentage) metric, where the weight for a class depends on the number instances of that class. 
Let us define the following for three classes, `A`, `B`  and `C`: 
  -
 `C_A`, `C_B` and `C_C` be the number of correct predictions in corresponding classes; 
 - `N_A`, `N_B`, `N_C` be the number of instances in each of these classes;
 - `N_A+N_B+N_C = T` as total number of instances. 

Then, your objective function translates to: `C_A/N_A + C_B/N_B + C_C/N_C`. 
Which can also be written as: `(C_A/T)*(T/N_A) + (C_B/T)*(T/N_B) + (C_C/T)*(T/N_C)`. 
This can be directly compared to overall accuracy as: `C_A/T + C_B/T + C_C/T` 

This means you can indirectly optimize your objective by using "multi:softmax" inbuilt objective function in xgboost.